# How to enable streaming app with SE for android

Tags: java, android, sdk, selinux

I've asked a question about an Ionic app with a HTML audio stream that didn't work correctly with certain Android phones.

I've identified that the problem is the "Enforcing" mode in SE for Android.

Since I haven't found any solution for the issue with Ionic/Cordova, I've decided to start the app with the native Android SDK.

Unfortunately, I'm having the same issue with the native SDK: the stream don't work in phones with SE for Android set in "Enforcing".

The phones I've identified with the problem are Samsung Galaxy S6, Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge, Samsung Galaxy Note 5 and Sony Xperia Z4.

This is the java code of app:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.io.IOException;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;


public class Player extends AppCompatActivity {
    private MediaPlayer mp;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);
        mp = new MediaPlayer();
        mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        try{
            mp.setDataSource("http://69.175.58.196:80/stream");
            mp.prepareAsync();
            mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mp.start();
                }
            });
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the content of AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.goradio.ovoradioclub">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".Player">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

It's seems that I'm missing something related to SE.

I'm also a Linux System Adminsitrator, and the only way I know to deal with SE is going with root access.

The idea of the app is for being in the PlayStore for free, so people can just listen to the stream, so rooting the device to disable SE is not an option for me.

Comment: "I've identified that the problem is the "Enforcing" mode in SE for Android" -- um, how have you determined this? What are your exact symptoms?

Comment: Because the phones with SE for android in "Enforcing" are the only ones that don't work.

Sorry, I haven't found much info about SE Android in google. I've determined that based on experience with SELinux.

Comment: That does not explain what your symptoms are.

Comment: The symptom is that in the phones that have SE in "Enforcing" mode, the stream just never starts. No error shown, or nothing else, it just doesn't work.

Any other phone it works perfectly, the app starts and the stream starts playing.

Answer (score 0):

> It's seems that I'm missing something related to SE.

I just ran your code on a Nexus 5, running Android 6.0. `getenforce`, run on `adb shell`, on this device shows `Enforcing`. The stream plays just fine.
The same holds true for a Nexus 5X.

I do not doubt that you are having problems on the cited devices. However, it would appear that the SE Enforcing state is a coincidence, not the actual source of your problem.

You might wish to look at LogCat to see if there are any interesting messages. Note that `MediaPlayer` has a tendency to log stuff at unusual severities (e.g., something I'd consider an error being logged at warning severity). Also, these messages are not going to come from your process, so be sure to look at all of LogCat, not a filtered view showing only your own process.

Comment: Didn't know about  LogCat. 
I'll test with it, and write here if I found any solution.